# Eclipse is there a way to change the pass of the resources

Tags: eclipse

So right now I am making a java project and when I add a folder lets say "cfg" and click properties the resource path is "/PROJECT_NAME/cfg" is there a way I can make the relative path simply /cfg?

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to achieve I believe possible with  virtual folders feature [read more...](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/06/10/resource-improvements-helios-feature-10/)